# Javascript - Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the form I have created in my website. I need to get the input values.

```
<div id="addPlayerForm" style="display:none;">  
  <form>
                <input class="my-input" type="text" placeholder="Name" 
                id="player_name"></input>
                </br>
                <input class="my-input" type="text" 
                placeholder="Position" id="player_position" 
                style="text-transform:uppercase;"></input>
                </br>
                <input class="my-input" type="number" 
                placeholder="Rating" id="player_rating"></input>
                </br>
                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn" 
                style="background:#01579B;margin-bottom:3rem;" 
                onClick="pushPlayer()">Add Player</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

This is pushPlayer() Function:
Here I have used getElementById to take the values from input. And also the name.value is getting undefined! And I believe trim() is not working as the value is undefined. But I don't know where am getting wrong.

```
function pushPlayer() {
var name = document.getElementById('player_name');
console.log(name.value);
if (document.getElementById("player_name").value.trim() !== '' && 
document.getElementById("player_position").value.trim() && 
document.getElementById("player_rating").value.trim() !== '') {
    var playerName = document.getElementById('player_name').value;
    var playerPosition = 
document.getElementById('player_position').value;
    var playerRating = document.getElementById('player_rating').value;
    firebase.database().ref('playersList/').push({
        Name: playerName,
        Position: playerPosition,
        Rating: playerRating
    });
    Materialize.toast('Player Added to the database', 500);
} else {
    Materialize.toast('Type the Details Dude ;)', 1000);
}

document.getElementById("player_name").value = '';
document.getElementById("player_position").value = '';
document.getElementById("player_rating").value = '';
document.getElementById("player_name").focus();
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
at pushPlayer (script.js:312)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):409)
pushPlayer @ script.js:312
onclick @ (index):409
```

Where is my mistake?
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: your code is working. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: what..??! i don't know why but am getting the error...

Comment: Actually i figured it out....i was using the same ID of input with another element.....